# standardScaler ValueError

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I am real beginner in python and i am actually not a programer.I load a csv file to python with pandas. And made a dataframe. Now my problem is that i get an error when i am tryin to use the standardscaler. The Error is ValueError: could not convert string to float: employ
I dont know how to solve this problem. Actually the values in the column 'employ' are integer. Would be glad if someone could help me.
This is my Code

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X= scaler.fit_transform(X)`
```

Comment: What is the X in `scaler.fit_transform(X)`?

Comment: i am trying to make a logistic regression. X is my dataframe. it cotains my undependent variables.

Comment: Show us an excerpt of the file that creates the error.

Comment: Years with current employer Years at current address  \
    0                      employ                  address   
    1                        17.0                     12.0   
    2                        10.0                      6.0   
    3                        15.0                     14.0   
    4                        15.0                     14.0

Comment: One guess: if you're sure your `employ` column is all numeric, maybe your header row was read in as a data row? I played around and saw that that error (could not convert string to float) usually gives the specific _value_ that's causing the error—which is why I think it's trying to do something with the _string_ `employ`.

Comment: thanks. That could be possible,but how can i find out if its reading my header row and how can i change it ?

Comment: Ah, yes, that's what's going on: your first two rows are both column headers (full description and short variable name). If you have a csv, then with pandas you can skip the first row when you read in the data: `X = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', skiprows=1)`

Comment: Oh yes that makes sence.That helped me thank you very much. No I have another ValueError which says that my data contains nan or infinity :/

Comment: Add the new error in the question.

Comment: @a.k. You'll have to deal with your missing data before you can use `StandardScaler`. Check out pandas' `fillna` for a simple way to fill things in. You could also take a look at sklearn's `Imputer`.